# how to create an array of boolean values and avoid unexpected behavior when re-rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, boolean

I'm coding I wordle clone using react, and I'm trying to give the player several attempts, and I want to track the state of each attempt so when he finishes typing and press ENTER I verify his attempt: so I set the following state

`const [verifieAtt, setverifieAtt] = useState(Array(6).fill(false));`

and the following console log `` console.log(`verifie att ${verifieAtt} index: ${verifieAtt[0]} type ${typeof verifieAtt}`) `` shows `verifie att false,false,false,false,false,false index: false type object`

so far so good, but when the component re-renders the same console log shows: `verifie att false index: undefined type boolean`, it's like all the values combine into one false value, so as a result when I try `setverifieAtt((prev)=>{prev[grid.row] = true; return prev});` I get the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property '0' on boolean 'false'
    at App.js:75:1
```

so is it normal for javascript to combine the values? and if so how to prevent it?

Comment: Can you provide some more code? The only thing I can see here is that you modify the previous value when settings state. You should not do that. The easiest way to change this is using `setverifieAtt((prev)=>{ const updated = [...prev]; updated[grid.row] = true; return updated });` instead

Comment: Please show all the parts of the code where you call `setverifieAtt`. It sounds like you're passing a boolean instead of an array somewhere. We need a [mcve].

Comment: @Bergi it was a silly mistake on my part, I was calling a cleanup function that setverifieatt to false